# Generalization of FTA

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I'm sure that this is not any hypothesis, but following came to my mind when I was reading complex analysis.

Consider a function $f(z)=z^n+g(z)$, where $g(z)$ is continuous (*not* necessary holomorphic) and it holds that $|g(z)/z^n|\rightarrow 0$, as $|z|\rightarrow \infty$.

**Question**: How to proof that there is a $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_0)=0$ ?

I belive it must be true since if we set $z=re^{i\theta}$, then we have a closed curve $f_r(\theta)$, when $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $r$ is fixed. Now $f_0(\theta)=a_0=(constant)$, but if $r$ is large enough we have $|f_r(\theta)-a_0|\geq |a_0|$, for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, so due to continuity there must be fixed $r_0$ and $\theta_0$ such that $f_{r_0}(\theta_0)=f(z_0)=0$.

I don't know how to make that intuitive proof rigorous but I think complex analysis methods are futile in this case.

Comment: Are you familiar with fundamental groups?

Comment: @EricWofsey No I'm not.

Comment: @EricWofsey  You mean something like that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289819/fundamental-theorem-of-algebra-using-fundamental-groups

Comment: Yes, the argument given there works to prove the more general version.